# What are the risks of allowing Web Password Managers on a Corporate Network

Tags: password-management

I recently encountered a situation whereby a manager decided that LastPass should be blocked from the corporate network.

There was a concern that people might have corporate account details stored in Lastpass.

Dashlane, 1Password are not blocked as I can get to both websites - LastPass is inaccessible.

I am trying to understand the risks to the business and how they could best be mitigated to avoid such problems.

What governance or security risks and issues are being addressed by blocking web password managers from the corporate network?

Comment: Turagittech - edited to make this not opinion-based

Comment: Just for those that might have a similar question, concern and trying to unravel the good or bad of Password managers, this article adds something extra to the conversation http://www.csoonline.com/article/3109709/security/keep-using-password-managers-bugs-and-all.html

Comment: I work at a large IT company. A password manager (with local storage of passwords) is standard software installed on every computer. It's an essential tool to have when you need to remember the passwords of about 50 different accounts. You might also want to lobby for such a tool so you don't need to use those insecure web-based ones.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that a password manager that has storage online presents the risk that corporate credentials could end up in public if that online storage is breached, so it is normal, even expected, for these to be blocked.

Password managers with local storage, however, can be a benefit in large corporate networks that don't have Single Sign On (SSO) as they reduce the risk of users either writing things down (as they need to remember too many passwords) or forgetting logins and then loading down the help desk for password resets.

We have a number of posts on here around password management, and there is a strong move across industries to make it easier for humans to do the right thing. Password managers can help in this respect, but read the associated questions for a more holistic view of what can be done.